# Objects and copy ctors created without RVO in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. Please consider the following code:

```
class foo 
{ 
 int f; 

 public: 
   foo(int f1=0) : f(f1) { 
   cout<<"In conversion ctor\n"; 
 } 

foo(const foo & rhs) : f(rhs.f) 
{ 
    cout<<" In copy ctor\n"; 
} 

 foo& operator=(const foo & that) 
{ 
    f=that.f; 
    cout<<"In = optor\n"; 
    return *this; 
} 

}; 

 foo rbv() 
  { 
    foo obj(9); 
    return obj;                        //named return by value [def. 1] 
  } 

   foo caller() 
   { 
      return rbv();              // return by value [def. 2] 
   } 

int main(void) 
{ 
   foo box=caller(); 
   return 0; 
 }
```

1. Are the definitions for RBV and NRBV correct as indicated in the 
   comments?
2. Is it mandatory to have an accessible copy ctor defined though it 
   is not called during RVO?
3. Without RVO, in the code blocks

   ```
      foo rbv() 
       { 
        foo obj(9); 
        return obj; 
       } 

       foo ret= rbv();
   ```

Are the following steps correct in creation of 'ret'

(1) a temporary ( say obj_temp) is created using copy ctor from obj, 
 stack object 'obj' destroyed,

(2) ret is copy constructed from obj_temp, obj_temp destroyed later;

which implies there are three objects, 'obj' , 'obj_temp' and 'ret' and two copy ctors involved.

Comment: What text do you see when you run it? Does it confirm your guess?

Comment: If you are new to C++, you have a lot more things that should concern you more than RVO. Most (probably 90% or more) of classes should not be copyable at all.

Comment: def. 1 is NRVO, def. 2 is RVO, an 'O' is missing and some typos in Q.1. @dlev Without optimization and considering only NRVO and calling rbv() instead of caller(), 1 conversion ctor, 2 copy ctors are called. This confirms my guess. With optimization only conversion ctor is called.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, Somehow I got interested in RVO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks right to me.
2. You have to have an accessible copy constructor defined if you are going to copy objects.  Even if the copy can be optimized away.
3. That sounds right to me, though the precise ordering might be implementation defined.  You would have to

Answer (score 5):

> Are the definitions for RBV and NRBV correct as indicated in the comments?

They are RVO and NRVO (Return Value Optimization and Named Return Value Optimization)

> Is it mandatory to have an accessible copy ctor defined though it is not called during RVO?

It is mandatory, the compiler has to verify that the constructors are accessible, if they are not, the compiler must trigger an error and fail to compile.

> Without RVO, in the code blocks

```
foo rbv() { 
  foo obj(9); 
  return obj; 
} 
foo ret = rbv();
```

The code, as it stands would require the following operations: Constructor taking an `int` inside `foo` to create `obj`. Copy construction in the return statement to the return temporary `$tmp1`, copy construction of `ret` at the call place from the temporary. Now, the compiler can elide the two copies by placing the return value (according to the call convention) on top of `ret`, so `$tmp1` and `ret` are the same memory location, and by constructing `obj` on top of the same memory location, so at the end all three objects can be a single object and no copies need to be performed.